# Excel - Generate chart axis values as a range from the min and max values in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to create a chart from a single column that allows the user to enter a year. I want to plot as a bar chart the number of times each year was entered. However, I want the X axis of the chart to include every year from the min and max year entered into the column, with no gaps in the axis range.

e.g.

**Data**

```
2000
2000
2001
2003
2003
2003
2003
2004
2007
2007
2007
```

**Chart**

```
8|
7|
6|
5|
4|                    XX
3|                    XX                      XX
2|  XX                XX                      XX
1|  XX    XX          XX    XX                XX
--------------------------------------------------
 | 2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007
```

As you can see, there is no data for the years 2002, 2005 or 2006, but the chart has an axis ranging from the minimum to the maximum year.

**How do I achieve this?**

I'm using the latest version of Excel (v2205 Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is to construct artificial dates, e.g., 01.01.2000. If you are not satisfied with the date display, you can select the appropriate cells, go to `Home` -> `Number` -> `Custom` and change the format to `YYYY`. This will display only the years, but still internally reflect a date. Another advantage of adjusting the format is that the chart theoretically already correctly reflects the years and not the artificial dates.

This is what the data looks like in this approach:

```
years  freq
2000    2
2001    1
2003    4
2004    1
2007    3
```

Based on this data, insert a column chart. Theoretically, this should already give you the chart you are looking for. If this is not the case, you can adjust the axis as follows:

Select the horizontal axis, right click and select `Format Axis`.

Under Axis Options: If not already done automatically, change the `Axis Type` to `Date Axis`. Set the `Bounds` as desired (usually minimum to maximum), the `Units` are 1 year and the `Base` is also years.

Under Field Number:
Change the `Format Code` to `YYYY`.

Finally, you can tweak the chart as needed, but your general goal of the column chart with empty years is achieved and looks like this:

[image: Colmun chart with missing years]

Answer (score 0):

You can use formulas to get the chart data source.

According to the row number (Add the `row()` and subtract the row number of the first year 2000), we can get one incrementing vertical column.

[image]

Then use formula `=IF(C2<>"",COUNTIF($A$2:$A$18,C2),"")` to get the count of each year.

[image]

And then you can select the range to insert a chart. As the range I select is bigger than cells include data, so there is empty space on this chat.

[image]